# Viewed count uses incorrect plural form for suffixed value

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, views, plurals

It seems that the viewed count below the question title uses the plural form based on the exact value, but not on the suffixed (rounded) one with `k`:

> [image: 2k views]

In this [particular case](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12418/176217), the correct translations plural form should be based on `2` thousands (must be `2k раз`), not the exact view count.

Depending on the exact view count, you may see the correct or wrong plural form on the page.

Exact view count that is visible on tooltip (cursor pointing device is needed) has a correct form, but `k`-form is wrong:

> [image]